# Give reasons how consistent hashing can lead to load-imbalance

Tags: http

// Give reasons how consistent hashing can lead to load-imbalance.

// 5 days ago on my exam i had this question, but i can only find how it will load the balance, does the question even makes sence? if so what would you have writte

Comment: I don't have an answer but due to this question I came across a great article that explains the concept. http://www.tomkleinpeter.com/2008/03/17/programmers-toolbox-part-3-consistent-hashing/